# TableView is not loading any JSON data Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have spent about three weeks trying to figure this out.  I can get the section title to view, but none of the JSON data is showing.  When I do a standard "array" contained in the file, it displays.

I have followed every tip and trick out there and I am stuck.

I think this may have something to do with AnyObject and String, but I am missing something.  Please see my code below:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var userFirstname: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var userLastname: UILabel!
}

class Profile2VC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userTable: UITableView!

var usertitles = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Mobile Number"]
var userinfo = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard
    let URL_USER_LOGIN = "https://www.myapp.com/myphp.php"
    let userid = "13"
    let parameters: Parameters=["id":coolid]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .get, parameters: 
parameters).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
               print(swiftyJsonVar)

            if let userData = swiftyJsonVar["user"].arrayObject {
                self.userinfo = userData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
               //debugPrint(userData)
            }

            if self.userinfo.count > 0 {
                self.userTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    self.userTable.reloadData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between 
presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the 
navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
     return userinfo.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", 
for: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
  //let userTitles = usertitles[indexPath.row]
    let userInfo = userinfo[indexPath.row]
    cell.userFirstname?.text = userInfo["first_name"] as? String
    cell.userLastname?.text = userInfo["last_name"] as? String
  //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: fruitName)
  //cell.textLabel?.text = usertitles[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the data inside the request closure, not outside. You may also need to dispatch the reload on the main queue

Comment: Share the repo over github and I'll take a look at this

Comment: @MauricioChirino I can’t do that due to a confidentiality NDA agreement.  I can just post this code here.

Comment: @Paulw11 so I need to use a dispatch main queue enclosure with a catch let?  I had that before and the json data was not parsing either

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Is your is your `cellForRowAt` being called?  Xcode has a powerful debugger. You can set breakpoints and step through your code to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for that advice.  Will debug print help me achieve this?  I need to familiarize myself with this proceeds slightly.  I  will report back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to reload your table view in main queue. Check below code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.userTable.reloadData()
}
```

And you are reloading it multiple times which is not good so Remove unwanted reload code and you final code will be:

```
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .get, parameters:  parameters).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
               print(swiftyJsonVar)

            if let userData = swiftyJsonVar["user"].arrayObject {
                self.userinfo = userData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
               //debugPrint(userData)
            }

            if self.userinfo.count > 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.userTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //self.userTable.reloadData() //Remove this code
```

And once your API call done, Make sure `debugPrint(userData)` is printing some data and then when you are reloading `userTable` put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` and confirm that it's calling.

Then if its calling and data is there from server, You are good to go.

But if `cellForRowAt` method didn't called then you need to check your `userTable` DataSource and Delegate if it's correctly connected or not.

Comment: I added the breakpoint at cellForRowAt, but it did not do anything.  Turning on the debugPrint did work correctly, it printed out . does seem to be obtaining the json.   But the table still is not displaying any data.  All the debugging options that I chose in Xcode show that it works correctly, JSON is entering the array, but it just is not displaying in the table.   I am considering wiping out the VC and starting over with static cells.

Comment: cann you share demo project of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
let API = URL(string:"http://www.myapp.com/myphp.php")
    let request = URLRequest(url:API!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            if String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) != nil {
                let data = data
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                let jsonData = json as! [[String:Any]]

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {

                let user = jsonData.flatMap { $0["user"] as? String }
                print(user)

                self.annocumentTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you for this info, but where do I put the Alamofire code?  I need to get a request based on a specific criteria.